# PHP - Stop image from caching when selected using array_rand

Tags: php, caching

I have an array of images, I'm using `array_rand` to select a random image and then using that as a background for a div.

I have tried adding a timestamp to the image, but I seem to be caching the array section variable instead, as the image doesn't change, only the timestamp.

```
$section = array_rand($img_arr);

<div style="background: url('<?php echo $img_arr[$section]['image'] . '?t=' . time(); ?>');">
```

Edit: It is working on a non cached test.

Comment: I think you need to investigate a bit further. Do a dump of the $section variable. Can't see anything wrong with the code

Comment: It is working on a non cached version.

Answer (score 0):

HTML cannot cache a PHP variable, used as key in php array.
If it does, it has become a HTML string and there must be an error during interpretation. Check error logs of nginx/apache.

You can also try CSS url() definition without single quotes since it doesn't require quotes.

```
<?php $section = array_rand($img_arr); ?>

<div style="background: url(<?php echo $img_arr[$section]['image'] . '?t=' . time(); ?>);">
```